# Is amserver.jar required to create policy in OpenAM?

Tags: openam

We have a requirement of creating policies and groups programmatically and I was able to create policies and groups successfully using `clientsdk.jar` and `amserver.jar`.

I tried creating policy without using `amserver.jar` but got `“java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/identity/entitlement/EntitlementException”` exception. On the other hand I am able to create groups without using `amserver.jar`.

Can you please let me know if `amserver.jar` is required to create policy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although there might be some bundling issues with the ClientSDK jar, but for now you need to put amserver.jar on the classpath too.

UPDATE: https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-2513 is now fixed, so theoretically you should be able to create policies only by using the ClientSDK (from version 11.0.0).